# Why html5 video loop create request each iteration

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I have **Disable cache** tick removed and still request is made on each video loop iteration(Only on chrome).

What `Initiator: Other` mean in chrome inspector network section? First time the video is loaded from the host, but after that all requests are loaded from `Other`.

Each iteration video size is the same, not **(from cache)**. Is that mean the browser download it every time?

Can it be avoided somehow without saving the video in localStorage(I saw it in similar question), because this solution will not work in private browser mode and localStorage have size limit?

**UPDATE**

With **Disable cache** checked
[image]

Without **Disable cache** checked
[image]

**UPDATE**

Bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=680063

Comment: Check the request and response with wireshark for more detail information. With wireshark you will be able to track this "Other" host.

Comment: [Disabling the cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883569/chrome-re-downloads-video-every-loop) did prevent this issue from occurring, but not now in the latest chrome. I recommend submitting a bug report to chromes team or put the video inside a canvas (if you want) -- I know this is not a good solution for now, but, it's all I can think of it. It's most likely a native chrome issue

Comment: Bug report to chrome sent

Comment: @Petroff link to bug report?

Comment: @CharlieS i didn't found it... and created new one https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=680063&can=2&q=html5%20video%20loop&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: What does your first response look like? I wonder if your cache-control headers are indicating revalidation is always required? You are getting 304's indicating it isn't modified.

Comment: I can't reproduce it again. With v55.0.2883.95 new requests are not made anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of this is that another process than Chrome [initiated the request](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network):

> Some **other process** or action initiated the request, such as the user
>   navigating to a page via a link, or by entering a URL in the address
>   bar.

In the case of Chrome, [video is decoded using ffmpeg](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/video) which likely is this *other* process. The process is likely reopening the file from the cache which is why the request is initiated, or, the cache only holds the latter part (or max content length in sum) of the file in case the file is large and has to re-stream parts of the content over again - though, you state that when cache is disabled this doesn't happen.

`localStorage` has a very limited size and is not very suitable for storing video data (it can only hold strings so video must be encoded as mime-64 which increases the size 33% + each char takes up two bytes due to unicode).

A better alternative would be to use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) - this can hold much larger data as well as store the data in binary format (Blob). But it comes with an initial limit as with `localStorage` but contrary to the latter method you can request a larger size which the user need to confirm. I haven't tested, but I would assume you will run into the same limitations with private mode as with any other storage mechanism.

Comment: I tried both cases with **disabled cache** checked and uncheck and still get request each iteration.

Comment: Ive can replicate the same thing on chrome, mozilla and on safari a new request is made each time it loads and for shorter videos it can be hard on the servers

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I had the same issue. I found that Chrome's tab crashes after a couple of minutes. It looks it happens only when `Disable cache` is checked, but if this still bugs you, you can store the video into the local storage. More code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480562/html-video-loop-downloaded-multiple-times).

Comment: I already test this answer, but `localStorage` break the the private browser mode, witch i must support, so i am looking for other solution.